# Android app unseen - Eclipse ADT

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I've been trying to start developing to Android.

I have eclipse with ADT plugin and Android SDK.

I've been trying to start Hello World with tutorials.

```
[2014-05-18 21:00:24 - saas] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
[2014-05-18 21:00:24 - saas] \saas\bin\saas.apk installed on device
[2014-05-18 21:00:24 - saas] Done!
```

In AVD i see app installed in system, but don't have an icon on desktop, even the app not starting..

The same problems on 2.2 and 4.0

Do you have any solution?

Comment: Is the app not present in the menu???

Comment: no, i don't know why..

Comment: check if the app is listed in applications manager...

Comment: yes listed, you have it written down in my question..

Comment: Uninstall from applications manager and run it again...

Answer (score 0):

You most likely got inproper `AndroidManifest.xml` file, with no Activity registerd for

```
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

I suggest you start with doing some elementary tutorials first.